# Unable to understand Cruise Control build error

Tags: svn, windows-server-2008, cruisecontrol.net

Please bear with me since I'm recent noob to Cruise Control. I'm getting following error while I force build process through dashboard.

```
ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.CruiseControlException: Source control operation failed: . Process command: C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\svn.exe log "http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx/svn/SampleProject/Source Code/" -r "{2015-06-08T13:00:07Z}:{2015-06-08T13:00:13Z}" --verbose --xml --username tom.bush --password ******** --no-auth-cache --non-interactive
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Sourcecontrol.ProcessSourceControl.Execute(ProcessInfo processInfo)
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Sourcecontrol.Svn.GetModifications(IIntegrationResult from, IIntegrationResult to)
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Sourcecontrol.QuietPeriod.GetModificationsWithLogging(ISourceControl sc, IIntegrationResult from, IIntegrationResult to)
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Sourcecontrol.QuietPeriod.GetModifications(ISourceControl sourceControl, IIntegrationResult lastBuild, IIntegrationResult thisBuild)
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.IntegrationRunner.GetModifications(IIntegrationResult from, IIntegrationResult to)
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.IntegrationRunner.Integrate(IntegrationRequest request)
```

After digging a lot through internet I have neither been able to understand the meaning of this error nor could find way to resolve this error. If you have any ideas about this error please share.

As a side note, I am trying to setup Cruise Control on Windows Server 8 and the Tortoise SVN version is 1.8.8.25755

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute command from error (C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\svn.exe log "http://xxx.xxx.....) from server which running CruiseControl and update question with reported error.

Answer (score 2):

Most times when CC.NET is reporting a SVN error (especially if you are just starting)...it is the identity (aka, the user) who runs the CC.NET Service....and the svn privileges.

So this is what I do.

Login the CC.NET machine ~as the user who is running the CC.NET service~.
The do a manual "svn list" command. (from a command line prompt)

```
"C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\svn.exe" list "http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx/svn/SampleProject/Source Code/"
```

Until you can do this from the command line prompt, CC.NET won't be able to do it.

Either you don't have permissions setup for the user to see svn-repository.   OR you have to do a "p"(ermanent) acceptance of a certificate (<

Once it works from the command line prompt, resume debugging CC.NET.

You have to remember that CC.NET is just a big fancy "caller" of other tasks.  Here you are calling the svn.exe command line tool.
CC.NET is running that .exe, but it has to be a legit call for it to work.

Comment: Thanks @granadaCoder..!! When I executed that command from command prompt it showed me a message saying that SVN was not installed correctly. I just re-installed SVN and error vanished.